# Cannot find module 'on-finished'

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, typescript

I'm trying to run a Node Server. I'm using Express and Typescript and VSCode as editor. If i compile and try to run my app.js I get this error:

```
> Error: Cannot find module 'on-finished'
>     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:440:15)
>     at Function.Module._load (module.js:388:25)
>     at Module.require (module.js:468:17)
>     at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
>     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\nodeProjects\node_modules\express\node_modules\finalhandler\index.js:16:18)
>     at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
>     at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
>     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
>     at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
```

My app.ts:

```
/// <reference path="_all.d.ts" />
import * as express from "express";
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Listening on port 3000!');
});
```

my tsconfig:

```
{
    "version": "1.7.5",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "outDir": "../cmpl"
    }
}
```

my projects structure:

```
- .vscode/
- cmpl/
- src/
-- node_modules/
-- public/
-- routes/
-- typings/
-- views/
-- _all.d.ts
-- app.ts
-- package.json
-- tsonfig.json
```

And i don't know where the problem is. If I'm looking into the node_modules folder. The module exists.

Greetz

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is

`import * as express from "express";`

I tested the exact same line on my app using express, threw nearly same error, therefore you'd be better off using a variable, like I always do, and it has never failed me.

`var express = require('express')`

Should have no issues whatsoever.

Comment: i will try if I'm home or at work. But the first way is the ECMA5 way or not? ... this is weird why this doesn't work...

Comment: No idea, I have ALWAYS used variable for requiring, which I believe is standard.

Comment: Ok i tried with the `var express = require('express')` and its not working :/

Comment: What issue are you getting now?

Comment: the same again. I think I know whats wrong... when I compile with tsc, the files are in `cmpl`. But the modules which my `.ts` needed, like express are not moved to `cmpl` aswell.... there are still in `src/node_modules` ... So what i can do? :/

Comment: I fixxed it using gulp. Moving all src assets to cmpl assets folder and then my code doesn't have any problem. Thanks to you.